# struts2-JQuery-plugin Connection Exception while starting tomcat

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat7, tomcat6, struts2-jquery

I just upgraded struts2-jquery-plugin version from 2.3 to 3.5 which is giving this problem while starting tomcat. I'm using tomcat 6.0.26, I got the same in tomcat7 also.

```
[DEBUG][main] 06 Mar 13:02:38 web.context.ContextLoader-Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
[INFO ][main] 06 Mar 13:02:38 web.context.ContextLoader-Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 20763 ms
[ERROR][main] 06 Mar 13:02:40 struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher-Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.init(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3838)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:898)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:168)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: Connection refused: connect - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:893)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1194)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
    ... 27 more
```

I've gone around some post that points to proxy config issue. I'm able to start the tomcat successfully sometimes. So this is not consistently appearing. Wondering what can be the cause ! 
It also shows something about memory. I guess because of the previous issue.

Comment: Please make sure that `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.0.jar` is present in classpath, also that it can be unzipped without any issues (probably the cause is in the corrupted archive), and also it would be better to add xerxes.jar to classpath, and thus SAX parser will be determined.

Comment: I am including the jar via pom.xml, so it has to be present there. I'll try with xerxes.jar.